# CKFinder error when browsering (Symfony4 + EasyBundle + CKEditor)

Tags: php, ckeditor, symfony4, ckfinder, easyadmin

Here's my stack :

- Symfony4
- EasyAdmin
- Webpack
- FOSCkEditor
- CKFinder

And here's my problem :

I got a form with a WYSIWYG field, and when I click on the "Image" icon, a popup open with all the properties of the image (size, alt, border, link, etc.).
As I installed the Symfony bundle "ckfinder", there's now a new button "Browser".

When I click on the button, a new window open, calling this URL :

```
/bundles/cksourceckfinder/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?CKEditor=article_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=fr
```

And here's the error I get :

```
No route found for "GET /bundles/cksourceckfinder/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php" (from "http://192.168.2.1:8000/bundles/cksourceckfinder/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?CKEditor=article_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=fr")
```

I followed the documentation but I think I missed something.

There is no file name connector.php in my code, should I create it ?

Here's my configuration for **fosckeditor** :

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'

fos_ck_editor:
    default_config: default
    configs:
        default:
            toolbar: full      
            fullscreen: true
```

And ckfinder's configuration :

```
ckfinder:
    connector:
        authenticationClass: App\CustomCKFinderAuth\CustomCKFinderAuth
```

Do I need to create a route ? A new template ? I'm stuck.

Please, if you know how to deal with this, help me !

Thanks and take care.

Answer (score 0):

Up !

I create my own template to choose the images and it works perfectly.